# Model associations callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to add a review section to my app. To be more specific, a user can leave a review for a shop and the shop can then reply to that review. But I'm not sure if the model associations and review table migrations I have are correct.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class ReviewReply < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :review, optional: true
end


class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.integer :rating
      t.references :shop, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As with an earlier question, you're better making `Review` reference itself when you have `ChildReviews` or ReplyReviews as you call them. It's much more scalable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Eyeslandic. Can you please be more specific and maybe show some code? I'm kind of new with rails!

Comment: I commented on an earlier question and included some links there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723086/rails-4-level-categories-association Good luck with Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecture:

[image]

## 1. CALCULATING RATING

console:

```
rails g migration add_rating
```

migration:

```
  def change
    add_column :shops, :average_rating, :integer, default: 0, null: false
    add_column :reviews, :rating, :integer, default: 0, null: false
  end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :reviews
```

shop.rb

```
  has_many :reviews

  def update_rating
    if reviews.any? && reviews.where.not(rating: nil).any?
      update_column :average_rating, reviews.average(:rating).round(2).to_f
    else
      update_column :average_rating, 0
    end
  end
```

review.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shop
  has_one :review_reply

  after_save do
    unless rating.nil? || rating.zero?
      shop.update_rating
    end
  end

  after_destroy do
    shop.update_rating
  end
```

review_reply.rb

```
  belongs_to :review
```

## 2. REPLY TO A REVIEW

views/reviews/show.html.erb:

```
<% unless @review.review_reply.present? %>
  <%= link_to "Write a Reply", new_review_reply_path(review_id: @review.id) %>
<% end %>
```

views/review_replies/form.html.erb

```
= f.input :review_id, input_html: {value: params[:review_id]}, as: :hidden
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things things that I would change if it's a real application (= not just something you're toying around with):

- I'd remove the `optional: true` from the two associations in `ReviewReply` since replies don't make sense (data-wise) if they don't have an author or aren't connected to a review.
- I'd also set these two columns in `review_replies` to `null: false`.
- You should think about adding some deletion cascades (either adding `dependent: :some_action` in models or using `on_delete: :some_action` on the database columns – I'd recommend the latter):

  - delete review replies when a review is deleted?
  - delete review replies when a user is deleted? (or just set it to `NULL` and then show "Deleted User" in the UI?)
  - delete reviews when a shop is deleted?
  - delete reviews when a user is deleted? (or just set it to `NULL` and then show "Deleted User" in the UI?)

Answer (score 0):

In your migration polymorphic relation for `reviewable` is set up incorrectly - unique index on `reviewable_type` will prevent adding multiple records, better use

```rb
t.references :reviewable, polymorphic: true
```

in modern rails it adds non-unique index on both columns by default (you can be explicit with `index: true`, but in any way this is different from two separate indexes on each column alone)

Also most probably you want your unique index to include user id so that each user can review each reviewable once:

```rb
t.index [:reviewable_type, :reviewable_id, :user_id], unique: true, name: 'idx_unique_user_review'
```

Reason for including both `shop` and `reviewable` is not clear, but it depends on your application and goals. If the shop itself is the `reviewable` (as suggested by `has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable`) - then `shop` reference is useless. But in fact if you do not plan on extending reviews on something other than shops - it's easier to go with non-polymorphic reference for now.

In large app it's better to have common name prefixes for related things, so `ReviewReply` model name is better. `belongs_to :review` is most probably not optional, it's very strange to reply to nothing. Also it will most likely have `belongs_to :shop` (also not optional) not `user`, since the shop is the one replying.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vasfed. Yes that is correct, I do not plan on extending reviews on something other than shops. You mentioned above I should go with a polymorphic association `(t.references :reviewable, polymorphic: true)` and in another part of your answer you're saying that I should not `(But in fact if you do not plan on extending reviews on something other than shops - it's easier to go with non-polymorphic reference for now)`. Sorry but I'm a bit confused... so I should just do this then: `t.references :reviewable`?  And the rest remains the same?

Comment: @Dev these are comments about polymorphic one being set up incorrectly and direction how to fit it should you chose to keep it. I’d just removed `reviewable` and left explicit `shop`

Comment: I updated my initial question according to suggestion you gave. Can you please check it out and let me know if what I'm doing now is correct?

Comment: @Dev now it's looking better. Comment on review_reply belonging to a shop (not user) is still valid. Also review most likely `belongs_to :shop`

Comment: Ok thanks for the help @Vasfed.. I haven't tried this yet but I'll accept this as a final answer. But just for the sake of having the correct code on my question, please change your answer and I'll accept it!